# Silly trouble understanding expression of a projection in a certain basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

This may be really silly but it's bugging me a little bit: I've been asked to compute the projection of $\Bbb{R}^4$ with the basis:

$$\{v_1=(1,2,0,1),v_2=(-2,1,1,0),v_3=(1,0,2,-1),v_4=(0,1,-1,-2)\}$$

Onto

$$W=\{v_1=(1,2,0,1),v_2=(-2,1,1,0)\}$$

In my mind, we can describe the vectors of $\Bbb{R}^4$ with:

$$v=a_1 v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 + a_4v_4$$

So the projection of $\Bbb{R}^4$ onto $W$ is just the map:

$$a_1 v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 + a_4v_4 \to a_1 v_1 + a_2v_2 \tag{$\star$}$$

But this doesn't work, we actually have to compute:

$$\frac{\langle v, v_1 \rangle}{\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle}v_1 + \frac{\langle v, v_2 \rangle}{\langle v_2, v_2 \rangle}v_2\tag{$\star \star$}$$

My doubt is: Why do we have to compute like $(\star\star)$ instead of $(\star)$?

Comment: your four vectors seem pairwise perpendicular  and the same length, so

Answer (score 2):

$(\star)$ and $(\star \star)$ are equal. To see this, try showing that
$$\frac{\langle v, v_1 \rangle}{\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle} = a_1,$$
then do the same for the other term. Hint: the basis $\left\{ v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \right\}$ is an orthogonal basis.